# How to pass Token of the first request response to the second request header, using Axios in an Ionic React app (2 Post Requests)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, axios

I want to register a user and save his partner's data at the same time. The first axios request creates the user and returns a token. I need the token as a header of the second request.
I have implemented as following 'doCreateAccount' but it is not working. It performs only the first request .post("xx/register", userData)

**Can someone tell me how to make two axios requests, where the second one uses the token taken from the response of the first one?**

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const CreateAccount: React.FC = () => {
  
  const history = useHistory();

  const doCreateAccount = () => {

    const userData = {
      eMail: getValues("email"),
      password: getValues("password"),
    };

    const partnerData = {
      cardType: "6",
      firstName: getValues("partnerFirstName"),
      lastName: getValues("partnerLastName"),
    };

    axios
      .post("/xx/register", userData)
      .then((firstResponse) => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(firstResponse.data));
        axios
          .post("/xx/cards", partnerData, {
            headers: firstResponse.data.token,
          })
          .then((secondResponse) => {
            history.push("/homePage");
            return secondResponse.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("sth happened in cards request");
            setIserror(true);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("sth happened in register");
        setIserror(true);
      });
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Online Registration</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
      <form>
            <h1>User Data</h1>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">E-Mail *</IonLabel>
              <IonInput type="email" {...register("email")} />
            </IonItem>
            {errors.email && <p>{errors.email.message}</p>}
        
              <IonLabel position="floating">
                Passwort *
              </IonLabel>
              <IonInput type="password" {...register("password")} />
            </IonItem>
            {errors.password && <p>{errors.password.message}</p>}
           
            <h1>Partner card data</h1>

            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">First Name *</IonLabel>
              <IonInput
                value={partnerFirstName}
                {...register("partnerFirstName"}
              ></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Last Name *</IonLabel>
              <IonInput
                value={partnerLastName}
                {...register("partnerLastName"}
              ></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
            
            <IonButton type="submit">Send</IonButton>
            <IonButton onClick={() => history.goBack()} color="danger">
              CANCEL
            </IonButton>
          </form>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default CreateAccount;
```

```
"@hookform/resolvers": "^2.4.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.1.1",
"yup": "^0.32.9"
```

Comment: Your code seems fine (apart from broken jsx, like closing `form` tag with, I guess you removed some parts), it should work. Are you sure your first request is not throwing with error?

Comment: @Danila, the first request is not throwing with errors, it creates the user. The second request catches an error:  console.log("sth happened in cards request");

Comment: Well, then your second request is actually working and your app performs both requests. You need to log the error to understand what is going on, or check network console. The problem is that second request crashes for some reason

Comment: In network console I get only /xx/register with status success 201, nothing else. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Hm, maybe there is a problem there `headers: firstResponse.data.token,`, I think you need to pass object with some key there, like `headers: { token: firstResponse.data.token }`?

Comment: @Danila, you are rightttt :) I was missing that. Thank you very much. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with how you setting `headers` in your second request, it expects object, not a string:

```js
axios
  .post("/xx/cards", partnerData, {
    headers: {
      // Use correct key here which your api expects
      token: firstResponse.data.token,
    }
})
```